# Html.ValidationSummaryFor is not displaying

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

The validation summary is not showing for the first name and last name.  In my database I have these fields set to "Not Null" so I would figure that these would be required.  Another problem I'm having is that some of the fields near the bottom that I have set to "Null" are requiring validation?

Model:

```
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Middle Initial")]
    public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
```

View:

```
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control boldgray", @placeholder = "First Name" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1 col-md-push-half">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MiddleInitial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control boldgray", @placeholder = "M.I." } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MiddleInitial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-2">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control boldgray", @placeholder = "Last Name" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add [Required](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute.

Try this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="First Name Required")]
[DisplayName("First Name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Comment: I'm confused because none of my fields have [Required], but some of them are still showing an error message.

Comment: I'm sorry not an error message, but some of the validation messages are displaying when I don't have [Required] on any of them. For instance "The Date of Birth field is required" is displayed, but I don't have it marked required.

Comment: If your field is of non-nullable type such as int (not int?) in your view model I think MVC still validates it whetehr or not you have [Required] attribute set. It should not do that for First and Last Name fields though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add [Required] for a validation to work.

```
[Required]
[DisplayName("First Name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[Required]
[DisplayName("Middle Initial")]
public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }

[Required]
[DisplayName("Last Name")]
public string LastName { get; set; }
```